# How to Get android WIFI security name (WPA/WPA2/PSK)

Tags: android, android-layout, wifi

i have create custom WiFi setting UI in android application but i am struggle to get security name like (WPA/WPA2/PSK) i.e when user click on the WiFi list item so it display network information like Status , signal strength etc. all information accessed except Security.

i have tried WIFi configuration , manager but i am not able to get exact security name please help me how to get this thing
i am attach screen shot for more understanding.

[image]

Comment: have you found your answer ????

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android: extracting wifi capabilities with contains](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23637433/android-extracting-wifi-capabilities-with-contains)