# How to get WiFi security (NONE, WEP, WPA, WPA2) from Android WifiConfiguration entry?

Tags: android, android-wifi, wifi

I need to get security type from `WifiConfiguration` entry. Is it possible?

```
String getSecurityType(WifiConfiguration conf) {
}
```

returning values `"NONE", "WEP", "WPA", "WPA2"`

**For those who think it's a duplicate question: I want to get information from `WiFiConfiguration` object and not from `ScanResult` object. It's not the same!**

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android: extracting wifi capabilities with contains](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23637433/android-extracting-wifi-capabilities-with-contains)

Comment: @ozbek No it isn't. I need to get info from WiFiConfiguration item not from ScanResult.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I can do it, simply:

```
import android.net.wifi.WifiConfiguration;
import android.net.wifi.WifiConfiguration.AuthAlgorithm;
import android.net.wifi.WifiConfiguration.KeyMgmt;

public static final int SECURITY_NONE = 0;
public static final int SECURITY_WEP = 1;
public static final int SECURITY_PSK = 2;
public static final int SECURITY_EAP = 3;

public static int getSecurity(WifiConfiguration config) {
    if (config.allowedKeyManagement.get(KeyMgmt.WPA_PSK)) 
        return SECURITY_PSK;

    if (config.allowedKeyManagement.get(KeyMgmt.WPA_EAP) || config.allowedKeyManagement.get(KeyMgmt.IEEE8021X)) 
        return SECURITY_EAP;

    return (config.wepKeys[0] != null) ? SECURITY_WEP : SECURITY_NONE;
}
```

so...

```
public static String getSecurityType(WifiConfiguration config) {
    switch (getSecurity(config)) {
        case SECURITY_WEP:
            return "WEP";
        case SECURITY_PSK:
            if (wifiConfiguration.allowedProtocols.get(WifiConfiguration.Protocol.RSN))
                return "WPA2";
            else
                return "WPA";
        default:
            return "NONE";
    }
}
```