# Get security type from configured network?

Tags: android, wifi, android-wifi, wifimanager

I'm looking for a way to get the security type from **networks which are configured but not currently in range**.  That is, from a `WifiConfiguration` returned by `WifiManager#getConfiguredNetworks()` as opposed to `WifiManager#getScanResults()`.  Naturally, this could only tell what security type was in use when the network was last in range.  That is good enough for my purposes.

The docs for `getConfiguredNetworks()` state:

> Only the following fields are filled in: networkId, SSID, BSSID, priority, allowedProtocols, allowedKeyManagement, allowedAuthAlgorithms, allowedPairwiseCiphers, allowedGroupCiphers

Therefore, the accepted answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28022809/how-to-get-wifi-security-none-wep-wpa-wpa2-from-android-wificonfiguration-e) and others like it will not work because it depends on the `wepKeys` field.  (It also doesn't have a switch case for its own `SECURITY_EAP` result.)

Is this possible using the limited information available from `getConfiguredNetworks()`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6866153/android-determine-security-type-of-wifi-networks-in-range-without-connecting-t

Comment: @KristyWelsh Not a duplicate.  That question deals with `WifiManager#getScanResults()`, not `WifiManager#getConfiguredNetworks()`.

Comment: Do you wish to check keyManagement ?

Comment: @SahilBahl I don't know.  Hence my question.

Comment: What was the problem with 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6866153/android-determine-security-type-of-wifi-networks-in-range-without-connecting-t

Comment: @SahilBahl If you're referring to [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19567423/1953590), the first method is similar to the code in the Q&A I linked.  It won't work because the `wepKeys` field will not be populated.  The other answers deal with `ScanResult`, not `WifiConfiguration`.

Answer (score 0):

This is my naïve  solution.  From what little I know of wifi security, I have a hunch that these conditions are necessary but insufficient to determine the security type.  Maybe someone who knows more can elaborate.

```
private static String getSecurity(final WifiConfiguration network) {
    if(network.allowedGroupCiphers.get(GroupCipher.CCMP)) {
        return "WPA2";
    }
    else if(network.allowedGroupCiphers.get(GroupCipher.TKIP)) {
        return "WPA";
    }
    else if(network.allowedGroupCiphers.get(GroupCipher.WEP40)
            || network.allowedGroupCiphers.get(GroupCipher.WEP104)) {
        return "WEP";
    }
    else return "NONE";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The configuration would only be in your Configuration list if you had added it.  You are correct, the other methods won't work in this case.  The only way I can figure you got here is that you had added the configuration when it was in range, but had used the Forget function later.  Now that you are out of range, you can't use the ScanResult, but neither do you have the information in your configuration to determine what the security was anymore.